# Nohup and input params is this possible?

Tags: command-line, input, nohup

The following prg requires some input after start in the next line:

```
./myApp param1 param2  -d /home/user/abc
```

Enter password:

Is something like this possible:

```
nohup ./myApp param1 param2  -d /home/user/abc "mypasswd"  &>> /home/user/abc/myoutput.out&
```

As written above the password prompt appears right after start in the next line. I'd be very greatful for a solution! Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you mean using positional parameters, yes, possible. But not recommend because parameters can be seen in `ps` and `top` outputs , which means it's not secure.

Comment: @Wiking: It redirects them if not already redirected. Most people would like to have their logs in a specific file, not the generic `nohup.out`.

Comment: @wiking   > What about bash-script and user input read var? --> is this using positional parameters as well, which can be seen in ps and top? Could you pls provide an example, I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: @Wiking Previously myApp didn't ask for a password until encryption was introduced. When I now start nohup myApp there is no passwd request. But the log output shows Enter password: (followed by an error). So I can't use nohup anymore.